# why cmake find the wrong library?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have this code:

```
file(TO_CMAKE_PATH $ENV{LIBLAS_DIR} LIBLAS_DIR)
find_path(LIBLAS_INCLUDE_DIRS liblas/liblas.hpp PATHS ${LIBLAS_DIR}/include)
message(STATUS Value before finding= ${LIBLAS_LIBRARY_DEBUG})
find_library(LIBLAS_LIBRARY_DEBUG liblas HINT ${LIBLAS_DIR}/../build/bin/Debug)
message(STATUS Value after finding= ${LIBLAS_LIBRARY_DEBUG})
```

and I am getting this value for LIBLAS_LIBRARY_DEBUG

```
Valuebeforefinding=
Valueafterfinding=C:/Local/LibLas/build/bin/Release/liblas.lib
```

I am sure that it is not picked up from cache as I delete build directory and as you can see the value of this variable is blank before calling find library, so it is not getting its value from cache.

Any idea why cmake get its value from a wrong place?

Comment: You did not tell us, what you expect. Is this library already installed on your system? You can exclude them by using `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` in `find_library`. Unrelated but still: Use quotation marks in `message`'s argument after `STATUS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in the `find_library` invocation: the name of the parameter is `HINTS`, not `HINT`:

```
find_library(LIBLAS_LIBRARY_DEBUG liblas HINTS ${LIBLAS_DIR}/../build/bin/Debug)
```